# How to flip a position? strategy.close() and strategy.exit()

Tags: pine-script

i have code:

```
strategy(title="StackOverflowExample", overlay=true, slippage=200, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.2)
long=crossover(sma(close, 10), sma(close, 20))
close_condition=crossunder(sma(close, 10), sma(close, 20))
stl=strategy.position_avg_price *0.97
strategy.entry("long", true, 1, when = long) 
strategy.close("long" , when = close_condition) 
strategy.exit("exit", "long", stop=stl, trail_price=strategy.position_avg_price*1.04 ,trail_offset=close*0.03/syminfo.mintick)
```

How to flip a position in both cases? (strategy.close(),strategy.exit())

Comment: solved by using qty=2 in both cases

Comment: It strange that qty=2 solved the cases. Exits never flips position

Answer (score 1):

It strange that qty=2 solved the cases. Exits never flips position. For flip you need opposite entry:

```
strategy(title="StackOverflowExample", overlay=true, slippage=200, commission_type=strategy.commission.percent, commission_value=0.2)
long=crossover(sma(close, 10), sma(close, 20))
close_condition=crossunder(sma(close, 10), sma(close, 20))
stl=strategy.position_avg_price *0.97
strategy.entry("long", true, 1, when = long) 
strategy.entry("short", false, 1, when = close_condition) 
...
```